# How to have a value from one Excel sheet propagate to other sheets, while being incremented?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, automation

I have an Excel workbook, which has 100 sheets in it, all the sheets are identical apart from A10 in every sheet.

In A10 of sheet 1 there is a value 101 which I typed in manually and A10 of all other sheets are blank.
Now what I want to do is, when i type 101 in A10 of sheet1 then I want to have 102 in A10 of sheet2, 103 in A10 of sheet3 and so on until sheet 100; automatically.

How to do this?

Comment: you would need VBA to do this. If you are looking at using formulas for doing it, then you will have to type the formula in all the remaining 99 sheets - which I assume - u do not want to do. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume A10 is a variable, otherwise you could just hard code it, and each successive sheet is incremented by 1, regardless of the value in sheet 1.  In A10 on sheet 2, you could put this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(SHEET1!A10),"",SHEET1!A10+1)
```

On each successive sheet, change the sheet reference to reflect the previous sheet number.  The ISBLANK function tests to see if A10 on the previous sheet is blank and displays a blank if it is (empty double quotes).  Otherwise , it displays a number 1 higher than the previous sheet.

As Prasanna notes in a comment, this would appear to require manually entering the formula on 100 sheets.  However, there is a way to accomplish the result in essentially one step.  It combines two things.  First, it is possible to enter the same formula on every sheet at once.  Right-click on one of the sheet tabs at the bottom and click on Select All Tabs.  If you then paste a formula in A10 of the current sheet, every sheet will get the same formula with that one action.  This will include Sheet1, so you would have to go back to sheet one and replace A10 with your value.

So how do you use exactly the same formula on every sheet, you may ask.  Glad you asked that question.  Excel has a CELL function that returns meta information about a cell.  One of the parameters you can request is FILENAME, which returns the full path, filename, and sheet name.  This can be parsed to extract the name of the current sheet and you can use arithmetic to change the sheet reference, then the INDIRECT function to actually reference the cell on another sheet using the resulting text.  For the CELL function to work, you must first save the spreadsheet so that it actually gets a filename.

As an example, to reference A10 on the previous sheet, you wouls replace the hard-coded expression `SHEETn!A10` (where `n` is the previous sheet number), with something like this:

```
INDIRECT("sheet"&VALUE(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+6,3))-1&"!a10")
```

I believe you can reference any cell on the sheet within the CELL function (I don't believe it needs to contain anything), so I used cell A1 to avoid a circular reference.  This extracts the sheet number by finding the position of the close bracket (which ends the filename), and adding a character count for the word "sheet" to determine the starting position of the sheet number.  I used a length of 3 because the largest sheet number will contain 3 digits (if it is fewer, the MID function just takes what is there).

I explicitly converted the result to a number (the VALUE function) to do the subtraction to get the previous sheet number.  Excel is actually forgiving about this and will do the math without the VALUE conversion, but for anyone using a different spreadsheet, this may be required.

The complete sheet name and cell reference is then built by concatenating the text around the sheet number using &.  The INDIRECT function turns this text string into an actual cell reference.

So if you substitute this expression in the original formula, every sheet will get the exact same formula (no need to edit it on any sheet), and it will calculate the required sheet reference on each sheet.

Comment: Hi Fixer,

Your solutions seem to be promising,

Another question which i'am struggling to find an appropriate answer is as followes:

There is a coloumn which has 1000 sets of datas starting from a2:a1001 and at a3 i have managed to find the highest value in that range which is 80 by using the formula =MAX(IF(a2:a1001>0,a2:a1001,FALSE)).

Now at a4  i want to find the second highest value in that range which is 75 and at a5 the third highest value in that range , which is 60 and so on.

Can you help me to find a proper answer?


Thanks in advance

Comment: The only mechanism on SuperUser to answer another question is for you to create a new question for it.  BTW, I figured out a way to do all 100 sheets in essentially one step.  I'll expand this answer.

Comment: tried to create a new question , but have to wait until 7 days which seems to be very far away at this moment. So thanks for your co-operation, Will be back with a question next week. And regarding the sheets question , it is already sorted.

Comment: Great that you developed a solution.  Save the info in my answer in case it's ever useful.  The 7 day thing happens especially to new users when they post a number of questions and/or answers that get heavily downvoted, particularly if that outweighs any upvotes.  It's usually a sign that the user isn't yet familiar with how to write good SU questions/answers.  It's important that questions be clear and understandable.  Take a look at the edits to your questions and other questions that have been upvoted.  Spend a little more time clarifying & polishing your posts.  You'll get the hang of it.

Comment: @EXCELLOVER - re: your next question, check out the LARGE function: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/large.php.  Save restructuring the data over and over and avoid circular references by just creating a new data column using the LARGE function.  Or just sort the original column or a copy of the original.  That will get you started during your hiatus.

Answer (score 1):

This Macro is sheet specific and must be put in the sheet vba module.

Right click on the sheet name at the bottom of excel and select view code.

Paste this code there.

close the vba module and change A10 on the first sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Count = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(Count).Range("A10").Value = Sheets(1).Range("A10").Value + Count - 1
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```